# How to use a function in a different file in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm brand new to vue and I'm trying to use a helper function, the arrayDateFormatter in one of the .vue files I have imported it. I'm trying to use it inside of the `mounted()` but it never gets called and nothing after it. **I don't get any errors in the console**

my vue file

```
<template>
.....
</template>

<script>
import archives from "@/4.objects/o-archives";
import fullBanner from "@/4.objects/o-full-banner";
import speakerInfo from "@/4.objects/o-speaker-info";
import newsletter from "@/4.objects/o-newsletter";
import dataLoaderMixin from "@/mixins/dataLoader-mixin";
import arrayDateFormatter from "../mixins/gloabalEventsDateFormate-mixin";

export default {
  components: {
   ....
  },
  mixins: [dataLoaderMixin],
  data() {
    return {
      speakers: [],
      talkInfo: null,
      archives: []
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const response = await this.fetchEventsByProject();
      console.log(response.data.data.listOnlineEvents.items);
      //nothing gets triggered after here
      const currentEvent = arrayDateFormatter(response);
      console.log('current event');
      console.log(currentEvent);
      this.archives = this.fetchData("archive");
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Helper function

```
export const arrayDateFormatter = (response)=> {
 //some code i have tested and it works by itself
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have to import the files this way

```
import {arrayDateFormatter} from "../mixins/gloabalEventsDateFormate-mixin";
```